# How to add elements from one class to another class list, python

Tags: python, class

```
class lista(object):
    listanumere=[]
    def printer(self):
        print self.listanumere
    def adds(self,numar):
        self.listanumere.append(numar)

class movies():
    def __init__(self,ide,nume):
        self.__nume=nume
        self.__ide=ide

listarez=lista
a=movies(1,"David")
lista.adds(a)
lista.printer()
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: unbound method adds() must be called with lista instance as first argument (got movies instance instead)
```

So my question is: How to make a class which contains a list of elements defined in another class, for example a class which contains the list of movies and some methods which modify the list for example add a new movie or remove a movie with a certain ID?

Comment: Code is unreadable, fix please.

Comment: You'll need to fix the code in your `__init__` method, it's unclear what the intent is there, you have several statements on the same line without indentation.

Comment: what do you want you `lista` class to do that a plain old list doesn't already do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up class methods and instance methods.  You probably wanted to do:

```
listarez = lista()
```

And then

```
listarez.adds(a)
listarez.printer()
```

Comment: I would also point out that `listanumere` is a class attribute, which means that every `lista` instance shares the same list, and that this might not be what OP intended. To fix, remove `listanumere = []`, give `lista` an `__init__` method with `self.listanumere = []` in it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer :

```
class lista(object):
    listanumere=[]
    def printer(self):
        print "\n".join( [ str(elem)for elem in self.listanumere ] )
    def adds(self,numar):
        self.listanumere.append(numar)

class movies():
    def __init__(self,ide,nume):
        self.__nume=nume
        self.__ide=ide
    def __str__(self):
        return ":".join( [ str(self.__nume) , str(self.__ide) ] )


listarez=lista()
a=movies(1,"David")
b=movies(2,"Goliath")

listarez.adds(a)
listarez.adds(b)

listarez.printer()
```

If I were you, I would go with a class derived from a dictionnary (e.g. {'ID string' : movie object }) with the right overload method (init, str,..). That way you take avantage of standard methods such as itertools, etc.